# Ошибка в коде при использовании for-each | Java

Tags: java, foreach, итераторы

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, почему при передаче reverse(list) в цикл for each компилятор выдает ошибку ?

```
public class Example {
    public static Iterator<String> reverse(List<String> list) {
        Collections.reverse(list);
        return list.iterator();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = List.of("1", "2", "3");
        for (String str : reverse(list))
            System.out.print(str + ", ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что конструкция foreach не принимает интерфейс Iterator, она принемает интерфейс Iterable, который является вершиной иерархии для всех коллекций Java, кроме Map. Посему вам не нужно вызывать итератор у листа, вам нужно менять сигнатуру метода и передавать туда сам лист.

```
public class Example {

    public static Iterable<String> reverse(List<String> list) {
        Collections.reverse(list);
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = List.of("1", "2", "3");
        for (String str : reverse(list)) {
            System.out.print(str + ", ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Но есть принципиально через итератор, то тут надо немного поменять

```
public static Iterator<String> reverse(List<String> list)
    {
        Collections.reverse(list);
        return list.iterator();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] arrStr = new String[]
        {
            "1", "2", "3"
        };
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(arrStr);
        Iterator<String> strItr = reverse(list);
        while (strItr.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.print(strItr.next() + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

так делать не обязательно, просто у меня нету метода `of`

```
String[] arrStr = new String[]
{
    "1", "2", "3"
};
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(arrStr);
Iterator<String> strItr = reverse(list);
```